# Ubuntu Server - Access webserver from other LAN computer, setting up SSH or FTP, closing ports?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, apache-httpd

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 x64 Server, with apache2 installed.
The setup is pretty much default configuration.

I have a few questions about;

`DocumentRoot`/`Static IP`/`Connect from LAN`/`SSH or FTP?`/`Firewall ports services`

- I changed the `default` DocumentRoot location in the configuration
  file from sites-available  to `/srv/www/000` from `/var/www`.

  Even though I changed `DocumentRoot` to the new location, in that
  same .conf file there are tags with `<directory /var/www/>
  </directory>`  which were there by default, should I correct this, or
  should I only worry about changing `DocumentRoot`.
- How can I change my ip address to a non-DHCP static ip? (I'm talking
  LAN) I want to know how I can connect to Apache server from another
  computer on LAN, but also make sure Apache isn't reachable from WAN. 
  (I'm not sure if it could be even be reach from WAN)
- Its my first time really messing with the configuration of Apache, I
  usually leave it at its defaults and just mess in `/var/www`. Since
  I'm not using a GUI or web browser, I can't program and check my work
  from the local machine, I need to access the webserver from another
  computer on LAN, how can I do this?
- I  have no experience setting up or using SSH, but I'd like to create a group for SSH put my user in it, change the permissions for `/srv/www/000` for this group to edit only and allow SSH to `/srv/www/000` or, should I try installing an FTP server?
- If the only services that will be running on this server are
  `apache2`, `php5`, `mysql`, `SSH` or `FTP`. How can I check for other
  services that I might not need, and check for ports which are opened
  and I might not need running. I'm not going to make this server
  public to the web, but I'd like the experience of locking it down the
  right way anyway.

Thank you for reading - I apprentice any advice.

Answer (score 1):

ad 1)

Every site have to have own DocumentRoot variable set...

ad 2)

You have to stop dhclient for LAN interface:

```
ifdown eth1
```

(I pretend, that LAN interface is eth1)

Then you have to edit file `/etc/network/interfaces` in this way:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.1.50
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    network 192.168.1.0
    gateway 192.168.1.254
```

Please, use right values, this is only example, which values you have to fill...

And then you have to set dns server in file /etc/resolv.conf:

```
search your.domain
server 192.168.1.254
```

(after `server` you have to add IP address of your dns server).

Then you can do:

```
ifup eth1
```

And you will have static IP address.

Ad 3) and 4)

I can recommend to you to have a DocumentRoot set to your `/home/username/html` directory and for uploading a web pages use [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/) program. It is similar as TotalCommander, for example, and can handle SCP in very good way. FTP server is not very secure... But if you would like use one, you can try a `vsftpd` package.

Ad 5)

Use:

```
netstat -tpln
```

for services, which are using tcp, for udp services you can use:

```
netstat -upln
```

Comment: If resolvconf is installed, you need to add `dns-nameservers 192.168.1.254` to /etc/interface instead of changing /etc/resolv.conf. See http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/interfaces for more information

Comment: @jofel I know about it, but you must pretend, that there is resolvconf installed and my solution is universal.

Comment: Your solution is in that way not universal, since for the case resolvconf or openresolv is installed, /etc/resolv.conf is overwritten by it regularly, so editing it is not permanent. Of course, if resolvconf/openresolv is not installed, your solution is the right one.